# SQL to detect score or rating changes for a player

Tags: sql

say i have a table where i keep track of players & their last scores as per dates.

example records are

```
playerA 100 March3
playerA 120 March4
playerA 10 March10
playerB 89 March11
playerB 50 March11
playerC 200 March12
```

i want to know all those players who dropped 80% in their score or rating on a given day (compare to previous score)

how to write an efficient query around this?

Comment: You should tag your query with the database you are using.

Comment: is March3 a datetime colum or is like you placed it, a simple nvarchar?

Comment: First, make sure your table has correct field types, especially date field. Consider doing it in your programming language since it will probably be too complicated in querying language (e.g. SQL).

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI standard method is to use `lag()`.  This assumes that the last column is a bona fide date, not some obscure string representation.

The idea is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(score) over (partition by player order by date) as prev_score 
      from t
     ) t
where prev_score <= score * (1 - 0.8)
```

Comment: not working, is syntax correct related to from keyword?

Comment: @kapilSpring . . . The syntax is correct for databases that support the ANSI-compliant window functions, which is most databases.  You haven't tagged your question with the database being used.